# binary representation using vim

Tags: vim

Is there an easy way to convert the following hex values to binary representation using vim.

00ab abcd ff01 1234

It should look like.

0000000010101011
1010101111001101
1111111100000001
0001001000110100

Comment: "Easy" greatly depends on the available environment. What prerequisites are allowed; common Unix tools, Python integration, etc., or does it have to be pure Vimscript?!

Answer (score 5):

Run both of these commands and it should convert the line from hex to binary. The first line just creates a lookup table for the 16 hexadecimal digits that returns its binary representation. The second line finds all hexadecimal digits and replaces it with the value returned from the lookup table.

```
:let t = {'0':'0000', '1':'0001', '2':'0010', '3':'0011', '4':'0100', '5':'0101', '6':'0110', '7':'0111', '8':'1000', '9':'1001', 'a':'1010', 'b':'1011', 'c':'1100', 'd':'1101', 'e':'1110', 'f':'1111'}
:s/\x/\=t[tolower(submatch(0))]/g
```

Comment: This works but its too slow for large files, is there any other faster approach.

Comment: How large are we talking about and does this really need to be done in vim?

Comment: basically im using the conversion in vim as a reference file to compare with another file which does the same conversion using c program.